# What is task in this example from cppreference?

Tags: c++, c++11, future, packaged-task

In the example of [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) description of `packaged_task` from cppreference, a class named `task` appears. What is it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> task([](){return 7;}); // wrap the function
    std::future<int> result = task.get_future();  // get a future
    std::thread(std::move(task)).detach(); // launch on a thread
    std::cout << "Waiting...";
    result.wait();
    std::cout << "Done!\nResult is " << result.get() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That `task` is an object. Name it whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`task` is an object of type `std::packaged_task<int()>`. It's created in the first line.

Comment: Heh. We've all had that experience. Don't let it bother you.